# Повторное использование объекта std::future

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11

Можно ли присваивать новое значение объекту std::future, не получив результата выполнения предыдущей задачи?

Например:

```
std::future<TResult> f; // глобальная переменная

TResult thread_func(params) { /* тут какие-то тяжелые вычисления */ }

// запрос "долгой" операции (может поступить до окончания предыдущего расчета!)
void RequestAsync()
{
    f = std::async<TResult>(thread_func, some_params);
}

// проверяем получение результата (например, таймером)
void CheckResult()
{
    if (!f.valid())
        return;

    TResult result = f.get();
}
```

Я тестировал этот код и не получил никаких ошибок, но сомнения в корректности такого присваивания остаются. К примеру, что будет, если несколько запущенных потоков вернут значение параметра одновременно?
Не возникнет ли утечка памяти, при попытке потока вернуть значение через уже перезаписанную async'ом переменную?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это Вы думаете, что Ваш код так работает. И, в целом, это логично. К сожалению, реальность такова, что код работает по другому. Вот как работает эта строчка:

```
f = std::async<TResult>(thread_func, some_params);
```

Если в `f` сохранена `future` предыдущего запуска `async`, то только после того, как завершится предыдущая операция, новый объект `future` будет помещён в `f`. Таким образом, при таком подходе, не более 2-х одновременно выполняемых операций может быть, и никогда в `f` нельзя будет поместить новый объект, пока старый не завершился.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, правда, я вчера уже это выяснил, просмотрев код operator=() у future ) В итоге пришлось создавать list из future объектов, а в таймере проверять их через valid() и еще wait_for(0) и только затем удалять. В целом future сильно разочаровал, думаю, задачу изначально надо было решать через обычные мьютексы.

Comment: @AlekseySokolov, c `std::future` нет никаких проблем, проблемы у `std::async`. Если его не использовать, то и подобных проблем не будет.